# One pixel size graticule in OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to visualize huge tiled images. I can zoom in to a level where I can differentiate the pixels of the picture. In such a zoom state, I'm looking to add a feature where I can display some sort of graticule to make a clear distinction between the pixels.

This should look like just as displaying some grid lines.

Considering the documentation I've tried adding the following:

```
// Create the graticule component
var graticule = new ol.Graticule({ 
  // the style to use for the lines, optional.
   targetSize: 1,
   strokeStyle: new ol.style.Stroke({
     width: 1
   })
});
```

In the documentation it sais that `targetSize` is `The target size of the graticule cells, in pixels. Default value is 100 pixels.`. So by my understanding if I'd set it to 1 it should show around the borders of 1 pixel yet instead it is way bigger.

How should I approach adding such a feature?